# PDF form signature and database

Tags: php, pdf, asp-classic, pdftk, fdf

I've got a form (Been toying with both an ASP and PHP) that is going to have the info saved to a database and then be signed by docusign ink.

I'm thinking the best way would be to pump out a PDF (Thanks to http://koivi.com/fill-pdf-form-fields/tutorial.php) which would help with the database part but not help with the signing part without PDFTK (Which I barely understand so would like to avoid unless I can get someone to guide me through it).

Is there a better way or am I stuck with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working with EchoSign on a similar project, as our CRM currently spits out FDF/PDF files for print.  We are now implementing EchoSign, but in order to "sign" the documents you need to use the API, I believe, or manually key data into the DocuSign interface.

What you'll most likely need to do is create a .NET web app (or other application) that will connect to the DocuSign API [here](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center), and allow you to "sign" the documents you require.

So essentially your workflow would operate as such:

```
User enters data into your ASP/PHP Application -->
Stores data into your database -->
Through a link, or some type of function, transmit the data (using API) to DocuSign -->
DocuSign transmits to your client for signage -->
You get signed document back via API or other supplied method.
```

It's best to have DocuSign handle the signage of the document, as they are certified and take some legal liabilities out of the equation.  You want to ensure that whatever you're trying to get signed can hold up in court.

Comment: I was hoping that there was another way because to be completely honest I am lost on how to use the API.

Comment: @alsu3 - If you look at (PHP) https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-eSignature-SDK/tree/master/PHP or here (ASP) https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-eSignature-SDK/tree/master/MS.NET - there are samples and code snippets to help you get started.  If you are a DocuSign client, you should have a support system with them to get started.  If you're unfamiliar with how to work with the API, you may want to take some time to go through the information they have provided at the above link.

Comment: Also - they will not write the API functionality for you, rather will guide you in a direction.

Comment: You can see the WIKI they have provided here as well https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-eSignature-SDK/wiki

Comment: I understand that I would have to do it. Just the first time I've done something like this so the guiding is really appreciative.

Comment: I would start with reading the WIKI, and maybe some code samples and snippets as you start.

Comment: Did this help you?  Were you able to get started?

Comment: Yes it did help. I finished it and while its rough around the edges it works.